# DualBoot, Ubuntu booting error - Kernel Panic - not syncing

Tags: boot, kernel

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on a Computer that had only Windows 7 and now I am having an error booting Ubuntu. When I select in the Grub to boot Windows, it works well but Ubuntu seems to have an error.

[image: Error Screenshot]

The laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad L440.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: Has this ever worked? Could you boot with a LiveCD and post the `/var/log/kern.log` `dmesg` and `syslog` that have a size larger then 1K to http://paste.ubuntu.com ? Please [edit] your question and add this information...